# Powershell exitcode from MDM

Tags: powershell, exit-code

I'm writing a powershell script that:

1. Downloads a file
2. Checks it's hashsum
3. If hashsum is correct it installs it
4. If hashsum is incorrect it does not install it

I have a problem, where I'm using an MDM to deploy it automatically on many machines at the same time. Feedback from MDM shows that installation failed - but installed file works as intended for sure. Therefore most likely MDM receives bad return value. MDM exits code are like this

- Success exit code equal 0
- Failed exit code not equal 0

So: How to make sure powershell script return Success after **3. If hashsum is correct it installs it**
Will *$LASTEXITCODE = 0* make it work?

Comment: What does "install" entail? You just copy the file somewhere?

Comment: File I'm downloading is .exe so all i do is "./file.exe install"

Comment: so after calling `file.exe install`, do `if($LASTEXITCODE -eq <the exit code you expect from file.exe>){ exit 0 }`

Answer (score 0):

Just use exit and the exit code you want. Like:

```
    Function CustomExit{
        Write-Output "This function returns exit code 1613"
        Exit 1613 # Custom Exit Code
    }
    CustomExit
```

to test just run the file and give out the exitcode

```
    PS C:\script> .\CustomExitCode.ps1
    This function returns exit code 1613
    PS C:\script> $LASTEXITCODE
    1613
    PS C:\script>
```